# Python. Selenium. Парсится лишняя информация, как скорректировать путь?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Html код страницы вот такой:

```
<div class="product_item__description ">
  <div>
        9 000&nbsp;
    <span class="rub">
    <!--noindex-->
    <b>&#8381;</b>
    <!--/noindex-->
    <i class="rub__old">руб.</i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="product_item__old-price">
                  10 000&nbsp;<span class="rub">
          <!--noindex--><b>&#8381;</b>
          <!--/noindex-->
          <i class="rub__old">руб.</i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Пытаюсь спарсить только вот это: " 9 000 " следующим кодом:

```
prices= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.product_item__description > div")
```

Получаем в prices массив цен. В большинстве случаев нет, тогда все хорошо колличество товаров = колличеству цен в массиве prices, но когда old-price присутствует то в массив prices записывается 2 цены " 9 000 " и 10 000 .

Вот собственно вопрос как сделать так что бы selenium брал данные только из первого div а второй где old price игнорил

Comment: дайте ссылку на сайт пожалуйста

Comment: view-source:https://youla.ru/voronezh/zhenskaya-odezhda

Comment: короче есть один способ, который сто процентов сработает, но я писал всю жизнь на C# + selenium, поэтомк мне потребуется немного времени, что бы адаптировать код по питон.

Comment: либо могу написать алгоритм, а вы его уже сможите реализовать. Как вам удобнее будет?

Comment: Ды просто алгоритм в двух словах ) для питона напишу!

Answer (score 0):

ну так отсеките результат, это же так просто `prices[0]`

либо

```
prices= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.product_item__description > div")[0]
```

**Update** вы сами создаете себе проблемы, попытавшись искать по общему селектору
сначала найдите товары ( product_item__description ), а потом в каждом ищите div

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.product_item__description)
for item in items:
   prices = item.find_elements_by_css_Selector("div")
   for price in prices:  
      if(price.get("class") == "")
          price_new = .....
      else 
          price_old = ....
```

пишу в блокноте, так что найдете и исправите на подходящие методы

Comment: товаров много и есть с одним дивом а есть с двумя, и при каждом парсинге получается массив с многими ценами и тогда не понятно какие изначения из массива выбирать, какие пришли от "product_item__description" а какие от "product_item__old-price"

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать массив который будет хранить вебэлементы (IWebElements в C#) и в него загнать ваш запрос `IWebElements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.product_item__description > div")`
 и после этого он будет содержать либо один див (если старой цены нет), либо 2 (если старая цена есть).

Теперь вы можете к своему `prices` присвоить значение `нулевого` элемента массива `IWebElements`, который и будет содержать актуальную цену.

Comment: Только проблема в том что товаров несоколько от 1 до 30 И если при парсинге названий колличество элементов массива равно количеству товаров, то при парсинге цены их становится больше на колличество элементов со скидкой(товары со скидкой могут быть хоть все хоть ниодного). Просто если товаров 15 и из них 5 со скидкой, то тайтлов в массиве будет 15, а цен в массиве будет 20, и как из этих 20 убрать те в которые спарсились из product_item__old-price, ума не приложу.

Comment: Да я понимаю, но в цикле, где у вас будет перебор всех элементов, вам надо добавить костыль, а именно не добавлять значение дива сразу в основной массив, а добавлять значение всех дивов в промежуточный массив, а после нулевой элемент этого промежуточного массива перекидывать в основной массив.